# unit testing VIPER protocols

Tags: swift, unit-testing, viper-architecture

After reading several posts and articles about this issue I'm still confused about how to test a method in a VIPER architecture (for example with Swift).

If I had this code:

Presenter class

```
protocol InteractorToPresenterProtocol: class {

    func showInfo(info: Info)
}

class Presenter {

    private var interactor: PresenterToInteractorProtocol?

    init() {}

    func makeSomeStuffInPresenter() {

        // make some stuff 
        ...
        interactor?.makeSomeStuffInInteractor()
    }
}

extension Presenter : InteractorToPresenterProtocol {

    func showInfo(info: Info) {

       print(info)
    }    
}
```

Interactor class:

```
protocol PresenterToInteractorProtocol: class {

    func makeSomeStuffInInteractor()
}

class Interactor {

    private var presenter: InteractorToPresenterProtocol?

    init() {}
}

extension Interactor : PresenterToInteractorProtocol {

    func makeSomeStuffInInteractor() {

       // make some stuff 
       ...
       presenter?.showInfo(info)
    }    
}
```

How should I test makeSomeStuffInPresenter method?

Comment: Make a Presenter and call the method? Unclear where the difficulty lies.

Comment: The reason why this is difficult to me is that the results of makeSomeStuffInInteractor are not returned in that method, instead another method is called.The results of  makeSomeStuffInInteractor are really obtained in my presenter showInfo method.

Comment: You make an interactor too, or you can use dependency injection to arm yourself with a mock of the interactor.

Comment: Yes, I can inject the interactor and mock it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the attached [sample.](https://github.com/navrozSingh/TechTest)

The basic understanding of viper architecture is below.

View: Manages the view displayed to the user.
Interactor : Handles the business logic.
Presenter: Controls the communication between View and Interactor.
Entities : Are the modal classes.
Router:  Is responsible for managing the Navigation.

Writing the unit test cases.

For Interactor : You can opt Interactor protocol to a mock class and call it's function with positive and negative cases and your Presenter will fulfil the test case expectation.

For Presenter : Similarly, you can mock Interactor, View and call Presenter function and view will fulfil the test case expectation.

In general, for each zone z in {V,I,P,E,R}, you can mock up to the other 4 with simulated simplistic perfection & repeatability so that the zone-under-test (ZUT) is the only zone whose real source code is being exercised (in isolation).

Comment: The attached sample is pretty clear!

Comment: @navroz it's appreciated if you can add code along with description. Because description will not help for beginners.